# Incrementing value in a loop yields different (wrong) value?

Tags: java, loops, floating-accuracy

I have spent almost all day trying to figure out why this is happening, I had code that incremented a float if it was not a whole number until it was a whole number, i'd trigger it by incrementing the value by 0.01 and the loop keeps incrementing it by 0.01 until it is an integer however it never stops, debugging it I noticed that the number to becoming increasingly inaccurate as the loop progressed leading to it being 0.0000066 out by the end.
I thought maybe the variable might had been being accessed elsewhere somehow so I created it simply in an empty "main" program:

```
float value = 0;
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    value += 0.01f;
}
System.out.println(value); // Displays 0.99999934
System.out.println(value == 1); // Just in case it's displaying wrong in println (displays false)
```

Why is this not 1 by the end? I don't think it could be anything to do with data types as i'm adding a float to a float.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer 0-99 is still 100 iterations. 100 * 0.01 = 1

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, it's going 100 times like it's supposed to. Doing `<= 100` would make 101 iterations.

Comment: Long story short: Do not check a float or double for equality. It (usually) doesn't work, as you just discovered. That's just how these data types work. For the long story, check the link provided by @RohitJain

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus The short version of the story is an unfortunate shortcut. Equality is the only part of the question's program that works. `0.01f` does not “work”, and `+` does not “work”, but `==` works perfectly. “Do not use `0.01f` and `+` if you do not understand how they behave” would be much, much better advice than “Do not use `==`”.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus For instance, changing `value += 0.01f;` to `value = i * 0.01f;` makes the condition `value == 1` true after the loop. The `==` was never wrong in this condition, only the use of `0.01f` and `+` were. Changing these uses of dangerous constructs to something more thoughtful fixes the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java's floating point numbers follow [IEEE floating point standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), and that means that a value such as 0.01 cannot be represented perfectly (it's a repeating decimal in binary).  There is a small error that is not visible when just displaying 0.01 (it gets rounded when converted to a `String`), but the errors accumulate upon every add (or any other math operation); you have displayed the visible effect.

You can use `double`, with twice the precision, to cut way down on floating point errors, but this too will eventually show the floating point error.  You can also use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which supports arbitrary precision.

Comment: I think I will use integers then divide. I will have to remember this, definitely wish this didn't happen..

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a problem with the [IEEE specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard) of floating points. If precision is important in your application you should instead use [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)